# updating multiple MS ACCESS tables with 1 spreadsheet

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba

I have a MS Access database with about 1000 tables. The Tables are independent of each other, that is they are **not** linked to each other. Basically each table contains records of stock of a particular good. The Names of each table is the name of the item, for example 125 gm Soap, 200 ml Oil, etc. and contains the following columns : -

1. Date
2. Daily Opening Stock
3. Daily Sales
4. Daily Purchases
5. Daily Closing Stock

Each day, sales/purchases of all the goods are recorded in accounting software. The End of Day report summary is generated in Excel Format. This report is a consolidated report of daily Sales/Purchases of all the goods, **row-wise**. The Columns in Excel are :

1. Date
2. Item Name
3. Daily Opening Stock
4. Daily Sales
5. Daily Purchases
6. Daily Closing Stock

Presently I have to manually open each table in Access & copy-paste the respective daily sales/purchases data from the excel report. I want to automate this process so that the record is automatically appended to each of the respective table, basis the Item Name.

In summary, I want to update multiple tables in Ms Access database file, from data contained in **1** Ms Excel spreadsheet.

Is that possible ? Your help would be highly appreciated.

Thanks, 
Thiru V. Klack

Comment: Yes, that would be possible, but your question is way too broad for this forum.

Comment: please help me narrow down. What should be the question so as to fil it the term "precise" ??

Comment: can anyone suggest a sample sql code or maybe some other method ???

Answer (score 1):

My first question to you is why can't the Access database match the data structure of the Excel spreadsheet? Updating 1 Access table from 1 spreadsheet is a lot simpler than what you're trying to do. Having 1,000 tables with the same data structure, where each table is named after a product, seems pretty fishy to me.

That being said, if you need to keep your 1,000 tables (I'm honestly surprised you're not hitting the DB maximum threshold for Access), there are ways you can make it work. I would suggest having a lookup table that matches the product (as it appears on the spreadsheet) to the table in Access it goes to. Then, you'd import the Excel data into a staging table, and run some VBA code to loop through the lookup table, running a query to append all the data from Excel into the appropriate Access table. Something like this:

```
private const STAGING_TABLE_NAME as string = "tDataFromExcel"
private Const LOOKUP_TABLE_NAME as String = "tGoodsToTableNames"

public sub AddData()

    Dim db as DAO.Database
    Dim rsItemLookup as DAO.Database
    Dim strSQL as string
    Dim GoodName as string, TableName as string

    set db = CurrentDB
    set rsItemLookup = db.OpenRecordset("select good_name, table_name from " & LOOKUP_TABLE_NAME)

    do while not rsItemLookup.EOF
        GoodName = rsItemLookup.fields("good_name").Value
        TableName = rsItemLookup.fields("table_name").value

        strSQL = _
            "insert into " & TableName & " (" & _
                "[date], " & _
                "[Daily Opening Stock], " & _
                "[Daily Sales], " & _
                "[Daily Purchases], " & _
                "[Daily Closing Stock]) "
            "select " & _
                "[date], " & _
                "[Daily Opening Stock], " & _
                "[Daily Sales], " & _
                "[Daily Purchases], " & _
                "[Daily Closing Stock]) " & _
            "from " & STAGING_TABLE_NAME & " " & _
            "where [Item Name] = """ & GoodName & """"

        db.Execute strSQL

        rsItemLookup.MoveNext
    loop

end sub
```

Again, I'm certainly not advocating you take this approach: If you can, I would strongly implore you to refactor your database to not have 1,000 virtually identical tables.

Comment: Hi Zack, Thanks for the reply. Will try and tell you whether the same worked for me. However there aren't 1000 **identical tables**. Each table relates to a product and its corresponding sale/purchase history starting from day 1.  Most of the products didn't start trading from day 1 and were introduced later at random dates. Moreover it is not necessary that each and every product is bought/sold everyday, therefore data content is not equal. Pardon me but in my opinion approx. 2000 tables can be made. So I am way short to that number.

Comment: The excel spreadsheet merely contains sale/purchase data for 1 single date, whereas Access tables contain sale/purchase data for the entire history of the shop. Logically they are way different, hence cannot be equated.

Comment: I would support @Zack, this table structure is bad. You cannot for instance easy rename product or make a report with sales statistics.  Much better if you have in Access just two tables - one with product description and second one with sales, structure like your columns in Excel, but instead of Item Name - Item ID. In this case all operations will be much easier. Don't mix up data structure and data content. Proposed structure will be able to keep data for any random dates.

Answer (score 0):

Zack's answer provides a way to do what you're asking, but recommends that you do something else. I'm going to try to demonstrate that what he recommends would work for your situation, and show you how to achieve it.

You want to transfer data in an excel spreadsheet into a relational database that holds the same data - usually to give better access/manipulation. The data is in a big table of one day, with a separate line for each product, and you want to be able to view the entire history of a single product, so you have separated out the tables.

This is going to significantly slow down the automatic transfer process - that long loop that re-writes and processes the SQL over and over. You *can* look at the data in that way without this setup though. Lets call this tblProductDetails

One table has your product information - things like the name of the product, how much it costs... The other has the in/out records of what was bought and sold, keeping track of stock on hand at any point. This second table is going to have a LOT of records, as it's a new record for each product that was bought and/or sold each and every day. We might call this tblInOut.

With a `Select` query you can save in Access, you can look at the history of any one product at any time - you can even set this as a variable so that when you open *the only query you save* it prompts you for the name of the product you want to look up.

I've mocked up a [4 product sample schema](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/2b3bb/8) for you with a query to show *all* the data, and another to show just the one product's history. You can use the second query exactly as is in Access' query builder (SQL view) where `'125g Soap'` (on the second last line) is mentioned in the query name so you know which query is which.

If you want to use just one query, do the same thing with one exception: on the second last line, where it says `'125g Soap'` replace the whole thing with `Product_Name` (without the inverted commas) and when you open the query, Access will give you a message box asking you to type in a product name.

This feature will only work if you type the name exactly right though, so you might prefer just to build a form so you can give the user a combo box with which to select the exact product name.

Comment: I'm really thankful to both Zack & you for your immense help. I really understand your concern in refactoring the database to a minimum logical level. I am thankful for your efforts. However, the reason I have to have 1000 different tables is because the access database is again refed to generate/calculate Moving Average Stock Levels, Re-Ordering Levels & Stock Chart, in the same accounting software which also generates statistical reports. The accounting software of its own data calculates only upto using past 1 year's data. This is a limitation of the software... contd..

Comment: To calculate various statistics and generate various costing-based decision reports, based on larger pool of data (i.e. using data for more than 1 year data points), I need to maintain a Ms-Access database, which is fed into the accounting software for various calculation. While I can always run a query to generate a report based on just 2 tables, the said accounting software cant. It needs to have table by table data, which it uses to generate Item by Item calculation/report, when any particular item is clicked. This calculation is also sometimes used for automatic ordering for .. contd..

Comment: goods which are hot selling items. The software automatically sends an order to the Company distributor when a particular stock level is breached. Since many goods are seasonal in nature, 1 year data for calculation of the same is not enough. It needs to have several years data for the calculation to be normalized and avoid unnecessary ordering in lean seasons. For this reason, I have to connect the Ms-Access database containing multiple year history of stock movements with the accounting software. Hope it clarifies. Once again immensely thankful.

Comment: By optimising the order quantity, no.of orders & re-ordering levels, I minimize the Stock Holding costs, Stock Ordering costs & many a times, I also get a larger discount from the distributor based on order size & order frequency. This helps me save about INR 1,200,000/- (about $ 20,000) annually. With the saving I can afford to give employment to 2-3 more young people, who help me out with various activities, which originally I had to do it myself and caused immense burden. My effort does not make a large difference but in my small way & establishment, I contribute my help to the society.  .

Comment: Do you mind me asking what accounting software you're using? I'd have expected that you could export data using SQL to create individual tables of data/move data to individual tables from Access to your accounting software so that the latter need never "know" the specifics of how you store the data in Access - it just gets it in it's language. Your `SELECT` statements essentially aught to be able to translate the schema from Access to accounting whenever you need to export it.

Comment: It seems like a strange connection between the two pieces of software where one "knows" and relies upon the others structure, rather than just the data therein...